# Calculate Ranking from previous occurrence in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am working with trying to do some rankings for my chess club.  I figured this would be a good chance to work on coding to find ELO.  The way I encode it is each year we reset the ranking to 1200 then calculate it.  So I have the vectors year, winner, loser and I want to make elo.  Winner and losers are just numbers 100-125 to identify person and I have 3 years of data.

So I am struggling with doing this correctly. My struggle is figuring out how to find the most recent score since when I look through each row, I need to search for the last time someone’s ID was called in either win or lose column.  Additionally, if year changes, I need to reset the ELO score (I think using unique(year) should do).

Here is what I have tried (the disp('here') is just to show me if it runs, which it never does):

```
for i = 1:length(Season2014toNow);
WID = WinteamID(i);
LID = LoseteamID(i);
Seasoni = Season2014toNow(i);

for j = i-1:-1:1;
    if WID == WinteamID(j) & Seasoni == Season2014toNow(j);
        Win_old_team_elo(i) = Win_new_team_elo(j);
        disp('here')
        break
    elseif WID == LoseteamID(j) & Seasoni == Season2014toNow(j);
        Win_old_team_elo(i) = Loss_new_team_elo(j);
        disp('here')
       break
    else 
        Win_old_team_elo(i) = 1200;
        break
    end
end

for j = i-1:-1:1;
    if LID == WinteamID(j)& Seasoni == Season2014toNow(j);
        Loss_old_team_elo(i) = Win_new_team_elo(j);
        break
    elseif LID == LoseteamID(j& Seasoni == Season2014toNow(j));
        Loss_old_team_elo(i) = Loss_new_team_elo(j);
        break
    else
        Loss_old_team_elo(i) = 1200;
        break
    end
end    


[Win_new_team_elo(i),Loss_new_team_elo(i)] = CalcElo(Win_old_team_elo(i),Loss_old_team_elo(i)) ;
end
```

Comment: Test if the 'WinteamID' vector is numbers  eg. does 'WinteamID(1)*WinteamID(2)' return a value?  If 'WinteamID' is text you have to use 'strcmp()' to get logic values for your 'if' statements

Comment: It does return a number if I do that

Comment: Also everything I use is a vector/matrix of doubles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code breaks for `i=1`, which is the first step in the outermost for loop

```
 for i = 1:length(Season2014toNow);
```

for i=1, we get a `i-1=0` in the inner loops

```
for j = i-1:-1:1;
```

which is the impossible instruction "start at zero and subtract one until we get to 1".

One route around this is to add an exception for `i=1` that allows us to skip this code that breaks the programme.  eg.

```
for i = 1:length(Season2014toNow);
WID = WinteamID(i);
LID = LoseteamID(i);
Seasoni = Season2014toNow(i);

%% New if statement
if i==1 %%initialise scores and skip the code breaking i-1 loop
   Win_new_team_elo(i) = 1200;
   Loss_new_team_elo(i)= 1200;

else %% do the preexisting code 

  for j = i-1:-1:1;
     if WID == WinteamID(j) & Seasoni == Season2014toNow(j);
        Win_old_team_elo(i) = Win_new_team_elo(j);
        disp('here')
        break
    elseif WID == LoseteamID(j) & Seasoni == Season2014toNow(j);
        Win_old_team_elo(i) = Loss_new_team_elo(j);
        disp('here')
       break
    else 
        Win_old_team_elo(i) = 1200;
        break
    end
  end

  for j = i-1:-1:1;
    if LID == WinteamID(j)& Seasoni == Season2014toNow(j);
        Loss_old_team_elo(i) = Win_new_team_elo(j);
        break
    elseif LID == LoseteamID(j& Seasoni == Season2014toNow(j));
        Loss_old_team_elo(i) = Loss_new_team_elo(j);
        break
    else
        Loss_old_team_elo(i) = 1200;
        break
    end
  end    


  [Win_new_team_elo(i),Loss_new_team_elo(i)] = CalcElo(Win_old_team_elo(i),Loss_old_team_elo(i)) ;

end %% closing the if statement I added
end
```

A second route around this would be to use the `find` function.  If my understanding of your code is correct you are aiming to find the first occurrence of `WID==WinTeamID` in the current year

```
%% Mask for current year
AllWinTeamID_ThisSeason = WinteamID(Season2014toNow==Seasoni)

%% Find the first ID that matches
% SYNTAX (condition, #items to return, order)
find(AllWinTeamID_ThisSeason== WID, 1,'first')
```

Which can be built into something to replace the j-loops in your code

PS. I can't see your `CalcElo` code.  I'm assuming it works and is correct.

PPS.  Other minor fixes to get to best practice MATLAB programming would be to indent code for legibility (highlight in MATLAB and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>), add comments with `%%` to explain what bits of code are doing, and to put your j-loops into a function and call that function, rather than have the same code copied out twice.

Comment: I am still not getting the 'here' to display.  Am I correctly using the breaks ?  Since I want to exit the loop once I find the last time the team ID happened

Comment: A `break` will exit a `for` or `while` loop... So yeah they probably do what you want if I understand your code correctly.  Regardless, the `disp()` occurs before the `break` so you should see 'here' displayed even if the breaks are doing something odd.   Try a line-by-line execution of the code?

Comment: some details here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html

Then use the 'step' button in the toolbar to go through the code line by line

Comment: So I do that and I am yet to find a case where j actually steps backwards.  The winteamId has length of 214000 with 315 unique numbers ( I was just doing a subset from 100 to 125 in my post).

Comment: So is the issue that I break for all conditions of the if/elseif/else ?  That way I only ever evaluate the first j?  EDIT: Yes it is